# Best way to store temporary QuestionID-AnswerID data

Tags: java, android

I'm developing a quiz app and I want to find an efficient way to save user's answers.

Each quiz has **30** questions and all I need to save is:
`questionNumber`, `questionId` and `answerId` and either the answer is correct or not.

I thought an array will be a good solution. Example:

[image]

Each row represents a question (`questionNumber`). The first column represents the `questionId` and the second `answerId`. The third column will contain either `0` (incorrect) or `1` (correct).

The third column (correct) is needed to sum the number of correct answers (it's faster to sum the third column instead of checking each answer any time).

**This isn't a SQL table - this info is temporary and will be destroyed as soon as the user finishes the quiz.**

I want to know if you have any other solutions, maybe better.

Thank you!

Comment: The answer mostly depends on what you are going to do with this table, and how your are going to read/write to it. Also, unless you quizz has thousands of questions, I doubt you need to be concerned about the performance of your data structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not a class?

```
class Answer
{
    private int questionID;
    private int answerID;
    private boolean correct;

    public Answer(int questionID, int answerID, boolean correct)
    {
        this.questionID = questionID;
        this.answerID = answerID;
        this.correct = correct;
    }
}
```

And an ArrayList

```
List<Answer> answers = new ArrayList<Answer>();
```

Then use

```
Answer answer = new Answer(1, 2, true);
answers.add(answer);
```

With an Array you will need to fix the array size every time you add a question with an ArrayList you can add as much questions as you want without care about the array size.

Anyway, if you questions will be always 30 you can create an Array too without problems.

About performances, well i don't see problems about speed/memory.

Comment: I didn't even think about using a class. Thank you!